# Azure function goes idle when running in Consumption Plan with ServiceBus Queue trigger

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have also asked this question in the [MSDN Azure forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/af787179-3fba-4ec0-86d5-bd820f0c7e07/function-goes-idle-when-running-in-consumption-plan-with-servicebus-queue-trigger?forum=AzureFunctions), but have not received any guidance as to why my function goes idle.

I have an Azure function running on a Consumption plan that goes idle (i.e. does not respond to new messages on the ServiceBus trigger queue) despite following the instructions outlined in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/370):

The configuration for the function is the following json:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyConnectionString": "Server=tcp:project.database.windows.net,1433;Database=myDB;User ID=user@project;Password=password;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;"
  },
  "Values": {
    "serviceBusConnection": "Endpoint=sb://project.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=SharedAccessKeyName;SharedAccessKey=KEY_HERE",
  }
}
```

And the function signature is:

```
public static void ProcessQueue([ServiceBusTrigger("queueName", AccessRights.Listen, Connection = "serviceBusConnection")] ...)
```

Based on the discussion in the GitHub issue, I believed that having either a `serviceBusConnection` entry OR an `AzureWebJobServiceBus` entry should be enough to ensure that the central listener triggers the function when a new message is added to the `ServiceBusQueue`, but that is proving to not be the case.

Can anyone clarify the difference between how those two settings are used, or notice anything else with the settings I provided that might be causing the function to not properly be triggered after a period of inactivity?

Comment: If you refer to a specific issue, mind to add a link? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have `serviceBusConnection` setting also in app settings in the portal?

Comment: @Mikhail - yes, I do also have  serviceBusConnection setting in the portal.

Comment: @SeanFeldman, I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. I linked to the Azure forum post and the GitHub issue that I think I am seeing. What other link would you like?

Comment: can you share your function app name either directly or indirectly (https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/Sharing-Your-Function-App-name-privately)?

Comment: @ahmelsayed Sure. The function ID is currently 28923d72-3cb4-40d9-8332-1dcf8758868f, running in EastUS.

Comment: I had same problem when:
 - created function with Queue Trigger
 - deleted target Queue
 - re-created it with same name

Solved with re-creating the trigger in the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest there are several possible causes for this behavior. I have several Azure subs and only one of them had issues with Storage/Service Bus-based triggers only popping up when app is not idle. So far I have observed that actions listed below will prevent triggers from working correctly:

- Creating any Storage-based trigger, deleting (for any reason) the triggering object and re-creating it.
- Corrupting azure function input parameters by deleting/altering associated objects without recompiling a function

Restarting functions app when one of the functions fails to compile/bind to trigger OR input parameter and hangs may cause same problems.
It has also been observed that using legacy Connection Strings setting for trigger binding will not work.

**Clean deploy** of an affected function app will most likely solve the problem if it was caused by any of the actions described above.

**EDIT**:
It looks like this is also caused by setting **Authorization/Authentication** on the functions app, but I have not yet figured out if it happens in general or when Auth has specific configuration. Tested on affected Azure sub by disabling auth at all - function going idle after 30-40 mins, queue trigger still initiates an execution, though with a delay as expected. I have found an old [bug](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-ux/issues/528) related to this, but it says issue resolved.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. When you say **Clean deploy**, do you mean completely deleting the function from Azure and re-creating it during the publishing process from Visual Studio, or something else? And could you explain 'legacy Connection Strings setting'? Since I do have a `ConnectionStrings` setting defined in my configuration I'm wondering if that is the problem.

Comment: @Heather_E
You have Application Settings and Connection Strings settings, but you should only use Application Settings section. Connection Strings is a legacy thing
Clean deploy means remove the function app and re-create it, then perform a code deploy from CI/VS. It may not be that easy if production is affected - so first try re-creating the function itself.
Please note that everything I wrote is for runtime 1.0.xxx

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I won't be able to test this until tomorrow, but you've given me a couple of things to try and I'll make sure to come back and mark your answer as correct if any of them work for me.